# Select columns based on a range and single integer using iloc()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the data frame below I want to select columns A and D to F.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

In R I could say

```
df[ , c(1, 4:6)]
```

I want something similar for pandas. With

```
df.iloc[:, slice(3, 6, 1)]
```

I get columns D to F. But how can I add column A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `np.r_` to pass combinations of slices and indices. Since you seem to know the labels, you could can use `get_loc` to obtain the `iloc` indices.

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('A'), 
            df.columns.get_loc('D'):df.columns.get_loc('F')+1]
# idx = np.r_[0, 3:6]

df.iloc[:, idx]
    A   D   E   F
0  38  71  62  63
1  60  93  72  94
2  57  33  30  51
3  88  54  21  39
4   0  53  41  20
```

Comment: Thanks! In my Problem the labels may change but positions are fixed.  `np.r_[0, 3:6]` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is np.split

```
df_split=pd.concat([np.split(df, [1],axis=1)[0],np.split(df,[3],axis=1)[1]],axis=1)
```

There you don't need to know the column names, just their positions.

Comment: Thanks Lepakk! However, this seems overly complicated for a task as simple as this. Check out the alternative solution from @ALollz. It achieves the same with much less code.

Comment: In this case, I think my solution is not that lengthy. But I completely agree, the more slices you want to remove from the original data, the more inconvenient the split/concat way becomes...